# Organize data in Python or Google Sheets from one sheet to another

Tags: python, excel

I was trying to organize some data, but I need help in writing a code for doing so. It would be intended to read a sheet with several rows, each row with a compound name and number of the best docking result from a test. It happens that, in another sheet, there are 100 docking results for each compound, not only the best one. I'd like that only the best results were appended in columns in the first sheet, according to the compound they belong to.

This is a part of the first sheet:
[image]

This is a part of the second sheet:

[image]

For example, this is what I was doing manually, pasting the needed information from the second sheet to the first sheet, according to the compound name and the best docking result (according to the number at the end of the file name in the first column):
[image]

It would be for a research I'm doing, I'm a bit worried I won't get through all the data in time.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add examples of your data as text instead of images and format it as a code, you can see hints while editing in editor. Describe in details the rule you use for merging the two lines and add any necessary info, such as are there any duplicate rows in your sheet? Is always row N related to row N in other sheet? Ping me after edit, I might be able to help.

Comment: Reading it again, you want the best result out of 100 results for each row in first sheet, but still cant figure out the rule how you get the "best" match, is it the match where rmsd and score are the highest possible while s(plp) is lowest? Do you have any formula to calculate the "best"?